# Why is Entrez email address not specified in biopython even if given my NCBI log-in email?

Tags: biopython

UserWarning: 
Email address is not specified.

To make use of NCBI's E-utilities, NCBI requires you to specify your
email address with each request.  As an example, if your email address
is A.N.Other@example.com, you can specify it as follows:
   from Bio import Entrez
   Entrez.email = 'A.N.Other@example.com'
In case of excessive usage of the E-utilities, NCBI will attempt to contact
a user at the email address provided before blocking access to the
E-utilities.
  E-utilities.""", UserWarning)

Comment: Can you add the complete code you are using? or a preferable a minimal, verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: After importing SeqIO and Entrez Module,                                                                                                 
Entrez.mail= "rubayet@example.com"                                                   
with Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide",rettype="fasta",retmode="text",id="AF191665.1") as handle:
    a=SeqIO.read(handle,"fasta")
    print(a.description)

Comment: It says Entrez.`e`mail, in your code you only use `Entrez.mail`.

Comment: Yup. Thanks @voiDnyx.  <br/> But I think for non-academic mail, a email should be sent to [link] (eutilities.ncbi.nl.nih.gov)

Comment: @RubayetulAlam No, you don't need to send any emai to NCBI.  You just need to have the line `Entrez.email = 'rubayet@example.com'` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Issue code:

```
importing SeqIO, Entrez

Entrez.mai l= "rubayet@example.com" with Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide",rettype="fasta",retmode="text"‌​,id="AF191665.1") as handle: a=SeqIO.read(handle,"fasta") print(a.description)
```

Solution:

replace `Entrez.mai l= "rubayet@example.com"`

with the following code:

`Entrez.email = 'rubayet@example.com'`

Note: Posting BioGeeks answer for the sake of getting this question out of the questionlist.